# mysql insert select syntax error

Tags: mysql, insert, syntax-error

The following SQL statement is valid and executes as expected:

```
SELECT r1.rs_objectidentifier AS parent,
       r2.rs_objectidentifier AS child,
       "satisfies" AS relation,
       0 AS root,
       0 AS leaf
FROM rsdata r1,
     rsdata r2
WHERE r1.weeknumber="1410"
    AND r1.weeknumber=r2.weeknumber
    AND r1.rs_variant=r2.rs_variant
    AND r1.rs_inrsobjectidentifieronelevel != ""
    AND r1.rs_inrsobjectidentifieronelevel != "Unknown"
    AND find_in_set(r2.rs_objectidentifier, r1.rs_inrsobjectidentifieronelevel)
UNION
SELECT rsdata.rs_objectidentifier AS parent,
       "" AS child,
       "satisfies" AS relation,
       0 AS root,
       0 AS leaf
FROM rsdata
WHERE rsdata.weeknumber="1410"
    AND (rsdata.RS_InRSObjectIdentifierOneLevel = ""
         OR rsdata.RS_InRSObjectIdentifierOneLevel = "Unknown")
```

when I prepend the select with the following insert statement, I get an SQL syntax error:

```
insert into traceability
```

The columns in the select match the fields in the table (as far as I can tell). The table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE `traceability` (  `Parent` varchar(50) default NULL, 
`Child` varchar(50) default NULL,  `Relation` varchar(20) default
NULL,  `Root` tinyint(1) default NULL,  `Leaf` tinyint(1) default
NULL,  UNIQUE KEY `Traceability_UI1` (`Parent`,`Child`,`Relation`) )
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Why do I get a MySQL syntax error when the insert statement as added???

The following error (not very informative) is...

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into
traceability select r1.rs_objectidentifier as parent, r2.rs_objec' at line 2
```

Comment: Please add an error message to your question.

Comment: @BKM - Tried it. Still errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
insert into traceability(Parent,Child,Relation,Root,Leaf) Select .....
```

Comment: Tried that one before but also just now again - same syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Solution was very simple. The SQL is part of a set of SQL statements. The statement posted above was missing a ; (to terminate the statement) so was running into the next statement and therefore throwing a syntax error.... *hangs head in shame*